# display: grid на 5 элементов

Tags: html, css, grid, display

Как правильно задать display: grid для пяти элементов блока так, чтобы три коротких блока были сверху, а два больших снизу?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Сделать сетку на 6 колонок и 2 строки. Три коротких в верхней строке будут занимать по 2 колонки, а два длинных в нижней - по 3.

Answer (score 0):

Простой и понятный вариант на [`grid-template-areas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template:
    'a a b b c c'
    'd d d e e e';
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.grid__item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.grid__item::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 33%;
}

.grid__item:nth-child(1) {grid-area: a;}
.grid__item:nth-child(2) {grid-area: b;}
.grid__item:nth-child(3) {grid-area: c;}
.grid__item:nth-child(4) {grid-area: d;}
.grid__item:nth-child(5) {grid-area: e;}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
  <div class="grid__item"></div>
</div>
```